# How to use one weight layer as a mask for the other

Tags: particles, weight-painting

Below is an image of a subdivided plane with 2 different weight layers and 2 different particle systems.

I am curious if there is a fast way to take the weight painting information for my red objects and use it as a mask for my green objects weight information?

- The result would make it so the red objects seemingly cut through the green objects.

Thank you so much everyone!!
[image]

Comment: you should look into the "vertex weight edit" modifier https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/weight_edit.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the [Vertex Weight Edit modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/weight_edit.html) or, more simply in this case, the [Vertex Weight Mix](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/weight_mix.html) modifier:

[image]

Which will let you subtract the band group from the circle group:

[image]

Ensure 'Use Modifier Stack' is checked in the particle system..